# Get a list of folders that my application has permission to access c# UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a way to get a list of folders that my Application has permission to access, and how would I add a new folder to the list?  For Example, Documents Folder, Picture Folder, etc.. etc..  And how to make this list of Folders persistent between application starts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`KnownFolders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders) static class to get common folders such as Documents, Pictures, etc. However, to be able to freely access them, you need to specify appropriate capabilities in your manifest (like 'Pictures Library', for example).

For any other arbitrary folder, you will need to explicitly ask user to pick it using [`FolderPicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers). You can then save this folder for future access using [FutureAccessList or MostRecentlyUsedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions).

There is a good sample covering all those options in [UWP samples repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FilePicker).

Comment: Also note that with the upcoming Spring 2018 update for Windows 10 we will introduce a new capability for UWP apps ('broadFileSystemAccess') that you can declare in your manifest to gain access to all folders the current user can access.

Comment: Let's say your application opens several folders using FolderPicker and then saves the tokens to a file under Local App Data.  Then, the program is closed and reopened, and the token file is reloaded... will the tokens persist between applictation starts?  meaning, can I reload the same folder using the old token from last application run without going threw FolderPicker again?

Comment: And by token you mean folder path? This won't work, as I said, you need to save StorageFolder item you got from picker to FutureAccessList to be able to reload it next time.